# A file named "off" located at /server/nginx

Tags: nginx

There is an "off" file in /server/nginx. It records error logs. I 've set error_log to /dev/null crit; in nginx.conf. Don't understand why this "off" file was created. How can I stop it from recording logs. My nginx version is 1.16

Below is the nginx.conf:

```
user  www www;

worker_processes auto;

error_log  /dev/null crit;

pid        /www/server/nginx/logs/nginx.pid;

worker_rlimit_nofile 51200;

events
    {
        use epoll;
        worker_connections 51200;
        multi_accept on;
    }

http
    {
        include       mime.types;
        
        #include luawaf.conf;

        include proxy.conf;

        default_type  application/octet-stream;

        server_names_hash_bucket_size 512;
        client_header_buffer_size 32k;
        large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;
        client_max_body_size 200m;

        sendfile   on;
        tcp_nopush on;

        keepalive_timeout 60;

        tcp_nodelay on;

        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 64k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 64k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 128k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length  1k;
        gzip_buffers     4 16k;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_comp_level 2;
        gzip_types     text/plain application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript text/css application/xml;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied   expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_disable   "MSIE [1-6]\.";

        limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=perip:10m;
        limit_conn_zone $server_name zone=perserver:10m;

        server_tokens off;
        access_log off;

server
    {
        listen 888;



        server_name phpmyadmin;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
        root  /www/server/phpmyadmin;
            location ~ /tmp/ {
                return 403;
            }

        #error_page   404   /404.html;
        include enable-php.conf;
        include deny-bots.conf;

        location ~ .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf)$
        {
            expires      30d;
            error_log /dev/null;
            access_log off;
        }

        location ~ .*\.(js|css)?$
        {
            expires      12h;
            error_log /dev/null;
            access_log off;
        }

        location ~ /\.
        {
            deny all;
        }

        access_log  /www/wwwlogs/access.log;
    }
include /www/server/panel/vhost/nginx/*.conf;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because of all the `access_log off` entries. That is not valid syntax, and it interprets it as a file named `off` :)

Edit: apparently the question missed a stray `error_log off`, with `off` being the file name. (Only) for `access_log`, `off` is valid to turn it off, apparently.

Comment: Can you please expand on this?

Answer (score 2):

I've found what caused the issue. It is because the example.com.conf at /www/server/panel/vhost/nginx/ (last line in nginx.conf). error_log: off is added in the location sections in this example.com.conf.

Changed error_log: off to error_log /dev/null; No log will be recorded in the "off" file.
Stop nginx, delete the "off" file, and start nginx. No "off" file will be created.

Comment: You can get better and faster answers by including full and correct configuration files.

Comment: and dont use administrative panels these are offtopic